# Trying to add another service to the meteor accounts package

Tags: authentication, meteor, accounts, meteorite

I've found this on github that shows how to add github login to the accounts. https://github.com/Jabbslad/accounts-github

Instead of installing the package with "`mrt add accounts-github`", I'm downloading the sources, and trying to make them work with a simple app. The goal of this is to make a few changes to the code to understand how it works and finally make my own extension to accounts.

But I get errors "`Cannot read property 'github' of undefined at app/accounts-github/github_common.js:1:36`".

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was the git for accounts-github was not updated with the latest evolutions from meteor. So I replaced "Meteor.accounts" with "Accounts" in all files and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

Because you added the package yourself you need to ensure the dependencies are also installed. You can find the dependencies in `package.js`

If you want to make the package from scratch ensure you also use a package in your meteor app. This means that you put your stuff in a directory called `accounts-github` in a directory called `packages` in the root directory of your meteor app.

You can also add these dependencies in yourself if you don't want to use a package:

```
meteor add accounts-base
meteor add accounts-oauth2-helper
meteor add http
```

Some dependencies should be in with meteor (i.e templating)

Comment: I added the packages, put everything in "pacakages" and I still get the error "Meteor.accounts is not defined" on github_server.js line 2

Comment: I replaced "Meteor.accounts" by "Accounts" in all files and now it works. Don't ask me why, I saw they were using Accounts in the doc, so I tried : http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_config

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I meant `packages`